# How to get child pageload event?

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery-Mobile.

On specific child page loads, I want to perform one JavaScript function.

So How do I get the child page load event?

Child page will be loaded with Ajax form submission. 
Somewhat like:
I have master page, in that I load page1 and submit it to page2. So response would be a page2 and with master page as hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fix for speed/quality: (less functin calls, no implicit checking of attributes)

```
$('#page2').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){

    //you code

});

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
//code
</div>
```

This is how it should be done since jQuery Mobile alpha3:

```
$('div[data-url="some.html"]').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){

    //you code

});
```

and no hacks in HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can put following JavaScript on parent page:

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
  if($(this).attr("id") == "page2")
  {
    //you code
  }
});
```

On the child page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
//code
</div>
```

Comment: With all the appreciation for your effort to help people I have to point out that it's not the best way to do this.

Comment: That's the why I put my questions to SO. I know someone will correct it out.

Comment: `$(this).attr("id")` is slower and harder than `this.id`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Am using jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js

```
$('#MapView').bind('pageshow', function() {
        console.log('show MapView');
       //Add Your Code here
        Reloadmap();
    });
```

The Page elements include

```
<div data-role="page" id="MapView">
//code
</div>
```